# Seeing Black and White Playback on a Kworld UB390-A USB TV Tuner

Tags: windows-7, usb, tuner-card

I have a TV Tuner from KWorlds. Broadcast as in NTSC Analog and gone through the Wizard where I had to choose country. My country is there. Myanmar(NTSC-M), but I am getting B&W video only and not color. Seems I can't Waka Waka yet. Help!

Answer (score 0):

Found what I was doing wrong. Apparently it's just a Saturation setting which was under Display. Never played around with Display as I thought Saturation would be unrelated to color gamut.